# CakePHP: How to safely remove database columns

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

We're having quite a complex SAAS app written in CakePHP (currently 2.4.7). Since we're really agile, we deploy a few times per day.

One recurring problem is the removal of database-columns. Here's the situation:

1. Our app runs in debug level 0
2. There are some long running cronjobs
3. We deploy a change and want to remove an existing db column (because it's not needed anymore)
4. After deployment, we remove all `tmp/cache/models` and `tmp/cache/persistent` cache files.

If we call ./cake schema update (or drop the column manually), our cronjobs break. (because they have the old referenced schema in memory and mySQL throws an error like '`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column`').

What are your lessons learned or tips for this scenario?

1. Temporarily changing app's debug level to 2 (= no caching) isn't the elegant solution I'm looking for.
2. Temporarily disabling all long running cronjobs is mission-critical and therefore not a real solution.
3. Scheduled downtimes are nice, but not very agile.

Bottom line:
Similar questions, like this one ([CakePHP: How to deploy DB schema changes to production without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050764/cakephp-how-to-deploy-db-schema-changes-to-production-without-errors)) are still unanswered in relation to long running jobs, so I wanted to re-ask the community again!

Comment: We had a similar issue and just stopped the crons before clearing the cache. What if the crons use the models you are changing?

Comment: @cornelb You're right. When the crons use the column/models we are changing, than we need to split the deploy. First: remove the functionality completely. Afterwards, in a second deploy: remove the column from the database. The underlying problem remains the same. Because the column is referenced in the cache files, every cronjob would fail again, if we would remove the column while running any cronjob.

Comment: The linked similar question, despite the comments, clearly indicates an app who has a stale cache after deploy (if the cache had been cleared there would be no references to whatever field had been deleted). Long running crons sounds like a poor-mans background job worker. The logical solution is to stop job workers from accepting new jobs, wait for or kill existing jobs, apply the schema change and then un-pause the job queue. Describing that in detail is involved, and  too broad for SO.

Comment: we're migrating the whole app from long running crons to job queues, but this is quite an effort :). so i hoped to receive a (more) simple solution for our problem.

Comment: Then you're probably looking to implement [signal handling](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pcntl-signal.php) so you can gracefully shut them down on demand. Depending on what your crons are doing - that might be trivial to implement, you can also do something ghetto such as dumping `if (file_exsts('/tmp/kill-everything')) { exit(1337;); }` into whatever looping code you have, and touch/delete that file as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can **NOT** update your cronjobs' queries with cake schema update. you have to update them manually